# optimizing loops, which is most suitable loop or conditional statement

Tags: loops, vbscript, conditional-statements

i am reading large xml file(600mb) and check values with a excel file. There i am using several loops and its taking time to execute. I thought about to replace some loops in to conditional statement

as this:

this function takes worksheet name as string and try to find the sheet(for all xml node)

```
function searchValue( val, rng, worksheet ) 
    set objWorksheet = nothing
    For Iter = 1 To objWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        If objWorkbook.Worksheets(Iter).Name = worksheet then
            Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(Iter)
            exit for
        end if
    next
```

What if I use select case and pass the sheet number insted of sheet name like below

```
sub getSheetNumber( worksheet)
    select case worksheet
    case "A"
        getSheetNumber = 1
    case "B"
        getSheetNumber = 2
    case "C"
        getSheetNumber = 3
    case "D"
        getSheetNumber = 4
    case "E"
        getSheetNumber = 5
    case "F"
        getSheetNumber = 6
    case else
        getSheetNumber = worksheet
```

Is that a good idea or is there any other way to avoid the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping of letters to numbers can be computed:

```
>> For Each c In Split("A B C D E F")
>>     WScript.Echo c, Asc(c) - Asc("A") + 1
>> Next
>>
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
E 5
F 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option besides calculating the value would be using a dictionary:

```
Set getSheetNumber = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
getSheetNumber.Add "A", 1
getSheetNumber.Add "B", 2
getSheetNumber.Add "C", 3
getSheetNumber.Add "D", 4
getSheetNumber.Add "E", 5
getSheetNumber.Add "F", 6

...

WScript.Echo getSheetNumber(worksheet)
```

Using `Select..Case` is overkill when you want to implement a simple key-value mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your requirement:

> this function takes worksheet name as string and try to find the
>   sheet(for all xml node)

Why not use Excel itself for looking up the worksheet?

```
function searchValue(val, rng, worksheet) 
    set objWorksheet = nothing
    On error resume next
    Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheet)
    On error goto 0

    If objWorksheet Is Nothing then
         ' Error! worksheet not found
    End if

    <..>
```